# html form action to php gives error 500

Tags: php, forms

I am just starting out with PHP, and want to get my HTML/javascript form to email via PHP.
So, the bits of the code that are relevant (both in same HTML document):-

(web address changed to protect the innocent, but they are both the same (cut/paste) in real life.)

```
<form id=emailform method="post" action="http://www.qqqqqqqq.co.uk/PHP/TestPHP.php"   enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

This gives:- Error 500 - Internal server error

```
<a href="http://www.qqqqqqqq.co.uk/PHP/TestPHP.php">Test PHP</a>
```

This runs the PHP code.

The PHP, which in this case is a simple echo, as the error occurs with any PHP I have, is:-

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
/* phpinfo(); */
   echo "This is a Test PHP echo test"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Have I done something really daft ? I thought that the action (if form valid) would behave similar to the link hence the second test.

Comment: The code provided will not generate 500 error. What does the web server log say?

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might help, putting quotes around your form's ID, also,

```
<form id="emailform" method="post" action="http://www.qqqqqqqq.co.uk/PHP/TestPHP.php"   enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="UTF-8">
```

A 500 error means "something has gone wrong on the web site's server but the server could not be more specific on what the exact problem is" - about.com

Try putting the quotes around the ID, and let us know what happens. That for some reason is a common mistake I make a lot, and I get the same issue.

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/500servererror.htm